# Scala recursive printing function for nested Arrays

Tags: arrays, scala, recursion, types, polymorphism

I am trying to write a helper method that can print arbitrarily nested arrays. My plan was to write a recursive method to handle this. I want to use typing to distinguish which method to call.

The base case is printing an array that contains Values, i.e not another nested array.

The recursive case is if the array contains another array, call print on the sub array.

Here is the code I wanted to write

```
object Helper {

  // Takes something that is an array of arrays and prints it
  def print[B <: Array[Array[AnyVal]]](data: B): Unit = {
    val sb = new StringBuilder()
    printSb(data, sb)
    println(sb.toString())
  }
  // Same as above but with string builder
  private def printSb[B <: Array[Array[_]]](data: B, sb: StringBuilder): Unit = {
    data.foreach(arr => printSb(arr, sb))
  }

  // Prints a value
  def print[B <: AnyVal](data: Array[B]): Unit = {
    val sb = new StringBuilder()
    printSb(data, sb)
    println(sb.toString())
  }

  // Prints an Array of values, not an array or arrays
  private def printSb[B <: AnyVal](data: Array[B], sb: StringBuilder): Unit = {
    data.foreach(b => "%s ".format(sb.append(printVal(b))))
  }

  // Prints a value
  def printVal(v: Any): String = {
    v match {
      case b: Boolean => if (b) "1" else "0"
      case i: Integer => "%01d".format(i)
      case v => v.toString
    }
  }
}
```

However the compiler has a tough deciding which print to dispatch method calls to (I think because AnyVal == Array[_] ???). I am looking for a nice way to express my requirements through types, is this possible?

Comment: Do you have the complete type information at the call site, or do you have only `AnyVal`s everywhere? If you had the full information, you could do it much nicer with typeclasses. That's very similar to `Show`, actually.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin yes will have full type information at call site, I will look into typeclasses. How would you use typeclasses in this specific instance?

Comment: jwvh's simple and pragmatic solution has put my first proposal in perspective. If calling the predefined `toString` method recursively, treating the arrays separately, is really all you want, I'd rather go with jwvh's solution, no need to overengineer it. If you are still interested in typeclass based solution, just take a look at the [`Show`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/show.html) implementation in scala-cats. This might be useful if you want to replace the predefined `toString` of involved objects by something else.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will try to implement using the pattern for Show too :) def loving the simple solution by jwvh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you're making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Start with something simple...

```
def stringAll[X](x :X) :String = x match {
  case arr: Array[_] => arr.map(stringAll).mkString("["," ","]")
  case _ => x.toString
}
```

...that works...

```
val a = Array(Array(Array(2,5),Array('c','t')))
stringAll(a)  //res0: String = [[[2 5] [c t]]]
```

...and add fancier transformations, `case b:Boolean => ...`, as needed.

Comment: Cool answer, definitely a lot simpler than what I was trying todo. It is easy to differentiate between the [][] case and the [] case too.

  def stringAll[X](x :X) :String = x match {
    case arr: Array[Array[_]] => arr.map(stringAll).mkString("\n"," ","\n")
    case arr: Array[_] => arr.map(stringAll).mkString(""," ","\n")
    case b: Boolean => if (b) "1" else "0"
    case _ => x.toString
  }